# Add state reference to Title Attribute in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, title

This is easier to explain with an example, so I made a plunker. In short, html has a title attribute which creates a pop up window with a description. The beauty of it is that it works in most screen sizes, etc unlike most pop up solutions.

My goal is to have some text in the title box that:

1. Looks like it's clickable.
2. Either executes some $scope.function (I would just use it for `$state.go()` or is a link to a ui-router state (`ui-sref`).
3. This is optional, but having a list in there would be awesome - but I am guessing there is no way to put html in there.

Is this doable? If not, what are my alternatives?

```
<p title="I want this to be a $state reference and do what the button does.">Some text that has a hover-over title.</p>
```

Before you look at this plunk - literally everything except the paragraph box above is irrelevant/environment set up for easy `$state` testing, so don't get put off by the amount of code.

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/DKWjEDQdcfNAsSxLPHAP?p=preview)

Comment: If you want to be able to click/attach events to the title, you should not use the built-in title attribute/feature. You should use either a library's tooltip/popover object, or roll your own. You can then use HTML and use event listeners and such on the content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like I am going to be trying to use  ui.bootstrap.popover for this, though I am still wrapping my head around how to use dynamically generated templates in there.